# Where is the chart that shows device model popularity?

Tags: hardware, android-versions

There is a box-chart that showed the list of android devices out in use, and the relative popularity of each.

I'm not sure if this is Google Developer provided, or by some 3rd party, but I'd like to relocate this chart of hardware popularity.

Does anyone know the chart I'm referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many third-parties do this statistical work. [Here](https://opensignal.com/reports/2015/08/android-fragmentation/)'s one I can find that's relatively new (Aug. 2015) and in English (Chinese groups do it too but I'd not bother looking for it because people here likely can't read). It's also interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Antutu, the popular benchmarking software records the make and model of each phone it benchmarks, and releases a [quarterly list of top 10 most popular smartphone](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.antutu.com/en/view.shtml%3Fid%3D8254&ved=0ahUKEwjCsLrf2qbPAhVFI5QKHTWuARkQFggcMAE&usg=AFQjCNGbv9mGLglBkHpaWts5AOFjZ2xiNQ&sig2=rVOuYfFjEc0OI5UcmNQq4Q) by relative percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some Android phone model charts:

[Unity mobile Android hardware stats (include Chinese manufacturers)](http://hwstats.unity3d.com/mobile/device-android.html)

[AppBrain Top Android phones](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-phones)